# Calling a procedure using another procedure in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, relational-database

I am trying to call a procedure using a second procedure.  The first procedure will create a file while the second procedure will call the first one for each record in a cursor.  My desired outcome is to have a separate file for each record.  When I run the procedure it will create on file and generate the following error:

```
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "PS.EXPORT_PROC", line 30
ORA-06512: at "PS.LOOP_EXPORT_PROC2", line 15
ORA-06512: at line 2
Process exited.
```

The first procedure is as follows:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE      "EXPORT_PROC"
(Psectionid number)

is
output_file_one     utl_file.file_type;

--------------------------------------------------------------

Cursor Crs is
select s.student_number student_number, s.lastfirst as student_name, 
cc.expression, c.course_name, t.lastfirst,
ps_customfields.getstudentscf(s.id,'blend_learn_score') grade
from
cc join courses c
on cc.course_number=c.course_number
join students s 
on cc.studentid=s.id
join teachers t
on cc.teacherid=t.id
where cc.termid in (2300,2301,2302)
and cc.sectionid IN(30024,30065, 30276, 30064, 30052)
and s.enroll_status=0;


-----------------------------------------------------------------
Begin


For rec in Crs LOOP
output_file_one := utl_file.fopen ( 'BLENDED_LEARNING',  rec.lastfirst || '-' || 
rec.expression || '-' || rec.course_name || '.txt' , 'W');
utl_file.putF (output_file_one, 'Student_Number' || chr(9) || 'Student_Name'||chr(9)||'Grade'); 
utl_file.fflush(output_File_one);

END LOOP;

For rec in Crs  LOOP
utl_file.put_line (output_file_one, rec.student_number || chr(9) || rec.student_name || 
chr(9) || REC.grade);
utl_file.fflush(output_file_one);
End Loop;

utl_file.fclose(output_file_one);

END;
```

The second procedure should pass in values to the first

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE LOOP_EXPORT_PROC2 

IS 

Cursor Blended_Crs  is

select distinct sectionid
from cc
inner join courses a on cc.course_number = a.course_number
where cc.termid >= 2300 and a.course_name like ('AR%') and cc.schoolid = 3;

BEGIN
For rec in Blended_Crs  LOOP

EXPORT_PROC(rec.sectionid);

End Loop;

END LOOP_EXPORT_PROC2;
```

It should loop around and create a file for every record in the crs2 in the second procedure but when running the procedure it will create one file successfully and generate the error listed at the top.

I have verified that the permissions to the directory are correct.

My question is can you think of any reason I would get that error?  Based on the code it should be able to run the first procedure once for every record in the second procedures cursor.  I am doing this so that I can pass different perimeters into that first procedure and have a different file for each perimeter.

Comment: There a numerous errors in your code. Please update so we can help.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, indenting code is fine, you should not add brackets, remove quotation and add ?? though. rolled back

Comment: @PatrickHofman Please do not change the code by adding missing constructs `end loop;` for instance and adding (un-commenting  in this situation) incorrect one - wrong use of `declare` keyword.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov: Sorry, I thought the declare fell of by accident, I will remove it. All other changes are logical.

Comment: I made changes to the code the scale it down and try to make it relevant to more people.  Sorry about the syntax errors.  I will delete this questions and re-post the original procedures.  They both compile but the second will generate an error.

Comment: Your updated code won't compile; the `rec."student_name"` will error because the alias isn't quoted in the cursor declaration. Simplifying or generalising code is great but not if it confuses the picture.

Comment: This seems to work fine, with dummy data. I think the proc-calling-proc is a red herring anyway, but don't know if you've tried just calling `export_proc` directly? Given the quoted-identifier issue you fixed, I'm still not convinced we're seeing all the real code; I'd specifically like to know what line 34 is in your actual code, and whether that is after the second loop. If I had to guess I'd think you had a `close crs` before the final `end`, left over from an earlier version; not sure how else you can see that particular error.

Comment: The code is unchanged.  I removed a few spaces and separator comments ---------------- but that is throwing off the line numbers.  The line it is referencing is 

output_file_one := utl_file.fopen ( 'BLENDED_LEARNING',  rec.lastfirst || '-' ||
rec.expression || '-' || rec.course_name || '.txt' , 'W');

Comment: I have tried calling the proc usiong export_proc but still no luck

Comment: Does 'no luck' mean a direct call also fails? Sorry, but I don't see how you can be getting that error, unless you're hitting an obscure bug. You're 100% sure there are no other references to `crs` in the bits you removed, even in what seem to be commented-out code? Can you compile exactly what you've posted and see if that still errors?

Comment: Yes, When I tried to execute it it produced the same errors.  I have updated the error message as line numbers have changed because I made a few changes.  This is the way it currently is and what error message I am getting

Comment: Huh? That's a completely different error.

Answer (score 0):

You have several syntax errors. For example:

```
select distinct FIELD4
from 
where perimeter1=TRUE, perimeter2 in (1,2,3);
```

should be

```
select distinct FIELD4
from 
where perimeter1=TRUE AND perimeter2 in (1,2,3);
```

You are missing a semicolon here:

```
Cursor crs is
    select field1 , field2, field3
      from table1
```

You are not closing your outer loop properly here:

```
For rec in crs LOOP
    output_file_one := utl_file.fopen ( 'DIRECTORY',  'file.txt' , 'W');
    For rec in crs LOOP
      utl_file.put_line (output_file_one, rec.field1 || chr(9) || 
                         rec.field2 || chr(9) || REC.field3);
    End Loop;
    utl_file.fclose(output_file_one);
```

You need to investigate compilation errors in your source code before posting questions here ideally. You can view errors after you have compiled using `show errors`.

Comment: `where perimeter1=TRUE` is not possible, you cannot use BOOLEAN expression in SQL, nor you can define columns storing boolean values.

Comment: Also semi-column after first cursor declaration is missing

Comment: Your procedures are probably invalid. check it with --> select *
  from user_objects where status = 'INVALID'

Comment: My mistake on the original syntax errors.  I altered the code to not make it very general but it looks like some errors made it in.  I have posted the original procedures now and they are do compile.